# One last question on the concept of limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I read through this post on the notion of limits [Approaching to zero, but not equal to zero, then why do the points get overlapped?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12287/approaching-to-zero-but-not-equal-to-zero-then-why-do-the-points-get-overlapped/12290#12290)
But there's one last question I have. [Trust me, it'll be my last ever question on limits!]
 It clearly says as you get closer and closer to a certain point you are eventually getting closer to the limiting point. I.e., as $\Delta x$ approches $0$, you get to the limit.

Let me give you an example which supports the above statement. Let's say you want to evaluate the limit $$ \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2} .$$ Sooner or later, you have to plug in $2$ and you get the answer $4$ and you say that the limit of that function as $x \to 2$ is $4$. But why should I plug in $2$ and not a number *close to* $2$? $x$ is certainly not equal to $2$, right?

Comment: You could keep putting numbers closer to $2$ in any $f(x)$ from left and right  sides of the number line and then see what value the function $f(x)$ is approaching! This is just another way to compute limit of a function.

Comment: Tagging note: you're *already* considering limits, so this is calculus proper, and certainly not "pre".

Comment: alok I edited the post to fix the TeX and some basic copy-editing; hope it's fine with you. @J.M. Seems I submitted my edits after you changed the tag to (calculus); I incorporated that in my edit.

Comment: @srivatsan.Thank You so much for formating it right.I have no idea on how to use TeX and edit texts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of The Squeeze Theorem.  A version of the theorem says that if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\neq a$ then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ provided that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists.  So, for all $x\neq 2$ we have

$$
\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=x+2.
$$

Thus

$$
\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2}(x+2)=4.
$$

You are really plugging 2 into the function $x+2$ and using Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: The link with the squeeze theorem escapes me.

Answer (score 11):

I would disagree that "we must plug in $2$". What is really going on is that you are breaking up the problem into simpler limits that can be done *as if* "by plugging in". Here are a few of the ideas that are going on "behind the scenes":

> **Theorem 1.** Let $f$ and $g$ be functions defined on an open interval $I$ that contains $a$. If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in I$, *except perhaps at $x=a$*, then
>   $$\lim_{x\to a}\;f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}\;g(x),$$
>   in the sense that either they both exist and are equal, or neither one exists.

The idea here is that the limit of a function depends *only* on what happens *near* the point, not *at* at the point. If you know the definition of a limit using $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s, this is more or less immediate, since we always exclude the case $x=a$ explicitly in that definition.

> **Theorem 2.** Some easy limits:
>
> 1. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}\; k = k$, where $k$ is a constant.
> 2. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}\; x = a$.

Note that we are not "really" plugging in $a$ in these two limits; these are limits that can be computed using the *definition* of limit.

> **Theorem 3.** Decomposing complicated limits into simpler ones: if $f$ and $g$ are functions, and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;f(x) = L$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;g(x)=M$, then:
>
> 1. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\Bigl(f(x)+g(x)\Bigr) = L+M$.
> 2. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\Bigl(f(x)-g(x)\Bigr) = L-M$.
> 3. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\Bigl(\alpha f(x)\Bigr) = \alpha L$ for any constant $\alpha$.
> 4. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\Bigl(f(x)g(x)\Bigr) = LM$.
> 5. If $M\neq 0$, then  $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to a}\;\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{L}{M}$.

These are the things you use to determine 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 2}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}.$$ 
Let $f(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ and $g(x) = x+2$. Then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are different functions ($g(x)$ is defined everywhere, but $f(x)$ is only defined on $(-\infty,2)\cup(2,\infty)$ ), but at any $x\neq 2$, $f$ and $g$ have the same value. That means that, by Theorem 1, we must have
$$\lim_{x\to 2}\;f(x) = \lim_{x\to 2}\;g(x).$$

Now, $\lim\limits_{x\to 2}\;g(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 2}\bigl( x + 2\bigr)$. By Theorem 3, part 1, we know that
$$\lim_{x\to 2}\;g(x) =\lim\limits_{x\to 2}\bigl(x + 2\bigr) = \left(\lim_{x\to 2}\; x\right) + \left(\lim_{x\to 2}\; 2\right),$$
provided both limits on the right exist. By Theorem 2 above, we know that $\lim\limits_{x\to 2} \;x = 2$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 2}\;2 = 2$. So:
$$\lim_{x\to 2}\;f(x) = \lim_{x\to 2}\;g(x) = \left(\lim_{x\to 2}\;x\right) + \left(\lim_{x\to 2}\;2\right) = 2 + 2= 4.$$
Each equality is justified by a theorem. Nowhere are we "plugging in", neither $2$ nor numbers close to $2$; we are evaluating limits using the definition and some results that afford us some short-cuts.

Where does that idea of "plugging in" come in? Because there is a class of functions for which limits can *essentially* be computed by "plugging in". These are the **continuous** functions.

> **Definition.** Let $f(x)$ be a function, and let $a$ be a number. Then $f(x)$ is *continuous at $a$* if and only if three things happen:
>
> 1. $f$ is defined at $a$;
> 2. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;f(x)$ exists; and
> 3. $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\;f(x) = f(a)$.

If $I$ is an interval, we say $f$ is "continuous on $I$" if it is continuous at every $a\in I$; we say $f$ is "continuous" if it is continuous at every point of its domain; we say $f$ is "continuous everywhere" if it is continuous at $a$ for every real number $a$.

So the functions that are continuous everywhere are precisely the functions whose limits can be computed by simply "plugging in" (evaluating), thanks to part 3 of the definition. Among the functions that are continuous everywhere are the constants and the polynomials (like $g(x) = x+2$ above). However, to *prove* that such functions are continuous and that you can evaluate their limits by simply plugging in, you must *use* the properties of limits mentioned above, which therefore cannot be established by simply "plugging in" (that would make the argument circular).

Comment: Shouldn't $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\alpha f(x) = \alpha L$? (Yes, I know what you intended... :) )

Comment: @J.M. Yes; thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To find a limit, we do not care what actually happens *at* $x = 2$.  We only care about what the $y$-values of the function are doing as we get *close* to $2$.  In other words, one way to think of the quantity
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x)
$$
is the following: How do the $y$-values of the function $f(x)$ behave when $x$ gets close to $a$?  If the $y$-values get close to one particular $y$-value (call it $L$), then we say $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$.

In your particular example, the function $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ looks like the line $x+2$, except it has a hole in it:

[image]

In other words, we have that $\frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2} = x+2$, *except when* $x = 2$.   The fact the functions are not equal everywhere does not bother us, since we are only concerned with the $y$-value of the function when $x$ is *close to* $2$.  Therefore, when computing limits (and only when computing limits), we can think of $\frac{x^2 - 4}{x-2}$ and $x+2$ as the same.  Now, it is easy to see that the $y$-values of the function get arbitrarily close to $4$ when $x$ approaches $2$, and therefore, we can write

$$
\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = 4.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Ok. First note that $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^{2}-4}{x-2} = \frac{(x+2) \cdot (x-2)}{(x-2)} = \lim_{x \to 2 } (x+2) = 4$$

Now if you want to plug in a number close to $2$, then try $x= 2 \pm \delta$, where $\delta \to 0$ and see what answer you get. You should get the same answer.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar.when i plug in x = 2+delta and x = 2-delta the f(x) values that i get are 4+delta and 4-delta

Comment: @alok: So what is the value of $4\pm\delta$ when $\delta \to 0$

Comment: I think @alok's trouble (legitimate in my opinion) is about the quotient vs. limit of a quotient, which was also discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-dy-dx-not-a-ratio.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: Your limit disappeared in the second formula.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar:It's 6+delta and 6-delta.It's analogous to the earlier problem.Any reason why you making me do this?all i see is the sign changing from + to - along with the number.By the way awesome blog chandru!

Answer (score 2):

An important point to consider is that you cannot actually "plug in" $2$ and get $4$.

When $x = 2$, you will have a division by zero, since $x - 2 = 0$.

When calculating $\frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2}$ for $x = 2$ using a computer, you may get $4$ due to rounding errors when you have set $x$ to a value very close to 2. This is due to the very fact that the function approaches $4$ as $x$ approaches $2$.