# Find $f'(a)$ of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

What is $f'(a)$ of the function $f(x)$?

$$f(x) = 2x^2 − 3x + 1$$

I have been trying to do it but I cannot figure out how to do it. Please somebody can help me.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $f'(x)$?

Comment: Yes I do know, it is 4x-3

Comment: Just replace x with a now.

Comment: $f'(a) \to \left. {\frac{d}{{dx}}f(x)\,} \right|_{\,x\, = \,a} $

Comment: Related: [Finding $f'(a)$ for a given value](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/finding-fa-for-a-given-value)

Answer (score 6):

When we write $f'(x) = 4x-3$, that means that $x$ is a *placeholder*. In other words, exactly what symbol we use is of little consequence. Thus, we have, for instance,
$$
f'(\color{red}x) = 4\color{red}x-3\\
f'(\color{red}5) = 4\cdot \color{red}5 - 3\\
f'(\color{red}\dagger) = 4\color{red}\dagger - 3\\
f'(\color{red}わ) = 4\color{red}わ - 3
$$
and, of course, $f'(\color{red}a) = 4\color{red}a - 3$.

The (almost) only time to be careful is when we insert specific numbers. See, we *might* have written $f'(5) = 17$, which is technically correct, but that makes it difficult to see exactly how the $5$ we insert affected the result. However, when using other symbols, like $a, x,$ etc., this is usually not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f'(x) = 4x - 3$$ by simply using that $$(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}$$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then you just plug $a$ in for $x$, so $$f'(a) = 4a - 3$$