# How to simpify this?

Tags: fractions

How to simplify following fraction?
I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work...
$$-a^3 (c^2 - b^2) + b^3 (c^2 - a^2) - c^3 (b^2 - a^2)\over (c-b)(c-a)(b-a)$$

Comment: Are there any other relationships between a, b, or c? What is the context of this expression?

Comment: I notice that if $b=c$, then the numerator is zero, so by the factor theorem the numerator is divisible by $b-c.$ Perhaps you can expand the numerator out and use long division to divide the result by $b-c.$ (There's probably a slicker way to do this . . .)

Comment: Others are probably going to give slicker methods (but tricker to come up with), so here's what I'm talking about: To divide by $b-c,$ I'll consider $b$ to be the "$x$", so we rewrite the numerator as $(c^2 - a^2)b^3 + (a^3 - c^3)b^2 + (a^2c^3 - a^3c^2)$. The first step in long division is to observe $b$ (the "$x$") divides into $(c^2 - a^2)b^3$ (the leading term in the numerator) $(c^2 - a^2)b^2$ many times. Multiply this by $b-c$ then subtract, then divide $b$ into the new leading term . . . You should be left with a remainder of $0$ after you subtract a second time.

Comment: In my rush to get that comment finished before I had to leave yesterday I didn't realize that $3$ subtractions (not $2$) will be needed. I carried out the long division just now and got $(c^2-a^2)b^2 + (a^3-a^2c)b + (a^3c-a^2c^2).$ In the same way that we knew that $b-c$ is a factor of the numerator, we also see that $b-a$ and $a-c$ are factors of the numerator. So now divide the polynomial two sentences back by $b-a,$ and then divide the resulting quotient by $a-c.$ **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** Of course, this is a bit more tedious than the answers shown, but it has the advantage of being essentially the same method typically encountered in college algebra and precalculus classes. See my answer at [Finding limit of a quotient](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61033/finding-limit-of-a-quotient). Finally, it's not really a trick to initially investigate what happens when $b=c,$ $b=a,$ and $a=c,$ since the only factors that could cancel are $b-c,$ $b-a,$ and $a-c$ (nothing else is in the denominator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hands on, the numerator is $$-a^3c^2+a^3b^2+b^3c^2-a^2b^3-c^3b^2+c^3a^2$$Write this as a polynomial in $c$: $$(a^2-b^2)c^3+(b^3-a^3)c^2+a^2b^2(a-b)$$ We can extract a factor of $(a-b)$ to give: $$(a+b)c^3-(a^2+ab+b^2)c^2+a^2b^2=ac^3+bc^3-a^2c^2-abc^2-b^2c^2+a^2b^2$$ Now write this as a polynomial in $b$: $$(a^2-c^2)b^2+(c^3-ac^2)b+ac^2(c-a)$$ from which we extract a factor $(c-a)$ to give:$$-(a+c)b^2+c^2b+ac^2=(c^2-b^2)a+bc(c-b)$$ (written as a polynomial in $a$) from which we take out $(b-c)$ to give $-ab-bc-ca$ So the numerator is $$-(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(ab+bc+ca)$$

Using the symmetry is the way to go, but note how writing as a polynomial in $c$ highlights the possible factors involving only $a$ and $b$ - which can be handy if you have no better idea how to start.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that replacing in the numerator $a$ by $b$ or by $c$  we find $0$ and the same thing for $b$ and $c$ so so we can write the numerator on the form
$$\lambda(a,b,c)(c-b)(c-a)(b-a)$$
Now to find $\lambda$ let $a=0$ then we have
$$b^3c^2-c^3b^2=b^2c^2(b-c)=\lambda(0,b,c)(c-b)cb$$
so $\lambda(0,b,c)=-bc$ and by symmetry we have
$$\lambda(a,b,c)=-(ab+bc+cb)$$
and the simplification is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of symmetry.  First write the expression in the more symmetric form:
$$
\frac{a^3(b^2 - c^2) + b^3(c^2 - a^2) + c^3(a^2 - b^2)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}
$$
Notice that

- The expression is unchanged in any permutation of the variables $(a,b,c)$
  (you should check this)
- Direct substitution of $a = b$ into the numerator gives $0$, meaning the numerator is indeed divisible by the denominator (by symmetry)
- Every term of the resulting expression must have degree 2, since the numerator is degree 5 and the denominator degree 3.

It follows that the result must be
$$
\lambda_1 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) + \lambda_2 (ab + bc + ca)
$$
For some values $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.
Plugging in a simple case like $b = 0$, $c = 1$ you can conclude $\lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_2 = -1$.

Comment: You can also conclude $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=-1$ from the fact that, as a rational function in $a$, the symmetric expression is a cubic with lead coefficient $b^2-c^2$ divided by a quadratic with lead coefficient $-(b-c)$.  Indeed, you can jump from there straight to the final result, $-(ab+bc+ca)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Start with
$$\eqalign{-a^3(c^2-b^2)&+b^3(c^2-a^2)-c^3(b^2-a^2)\cr
  &=-a^3(c^2-b^2)-(c^3b^2-b^3c^2)+a^2(c^3-b^3)\cr
  &=-a^3(c+b)(c-b)-b^2c^2(c-b)+a^2(c^2+bc+b^2)(c-b)\ .\cr}$$