# How to prove $r^3+1 = (r+1)(r^2-r+1)$

Tags: arithmetic

$r^3+1 = (r+1)(r^2-r+1)$
I know we can simply multiply equations in the right-hand side then we get $r^3+1$. However, is there any way to construct right-hand side without knowing it?

Comment: You can do polynomial division.

Comment: Yes: $-1$ is easily seen to be a root of $r^3+1$. Then you know $r+1|r^3+1$ and you can do polynomial division to find $r^2-r+1$.

Comment: Yes, you see that the LHS has -1 as a root, and thus you divide by $(x+1)$.

Comment: It helps but is it such a mathematical proof?

Comment: It's as much of a proof as showing that $4=2\cdot 2 $ by computing $\frac 4 2$.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you can use the Factor Theorem from college algebra (or precalculus). For examples, see my answer to [Finding limit of a quotient](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61033/finding-limit-of-a-quotient). However, I was curious as to whether I could come up with something else. It's a bit contrived, but you can fill in all the lower powers of $r$ (both signs, so they cancel) to get $r^3 + 1 = r^3 + r^2 - r^2 + r - r + 1,$ which can be regrouped as $r^2(r+1) - r(r+1) + (r+1),$ and now you can factor out $r+1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the three cube roots of $-1$ as $-1, 1/2 \pm i\sqrt{3}/2$ from De Moivre's formula, and multiply:

$$r^3 = -1 \to r^3 + 1 = 0 \\ (r+1)\left(r - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(r - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = 0 \\ (r+1)\left(\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2\right) = 0 \\ (r+1)\left(r^2 - \frac{2r}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4}\right) = 0 \\ (r+1)(r^2 - r + 1) = 0.$$

Hence, $r^3 + 1 = (r+1)(r^2 - r + 1).$