# Factoring a Sum of Cubes Without Prior Knowledge of the Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Many solutions related to factoring a sum of cubes suppose knowledge of the sum of cubes formula,
$$
a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)
$$

If you did not possess prior knowledge of this formula, how would you go about factoring a sum of cubes? I understand that some experimentation with distributing polynomials could lead to the formula, which could then be used. I think there must be a way to factor a sum of cubes without invoking it directly. For instance, how would you find some polynomial $p(x)$ such that
$$
p(x) \cdot \, (x+c) = x^3 + c^3
$$

Without first resorting to applying the sum of cubes formula?

Comment: We can show $a^3\equiv(-b)^3= -b^3 \mod (a+b)$ , so we can derive from this that $a+b$ must be a factor.

Comment: Consider $a^n-b^n$. Denote $a = x$. We have the polynomial $p(x) = x^n - b^n$, which has $x = b$ as a root, because $p(b) = 0$.  So $x^n-b^n$ is divisible by $(x-b)$ . Now set $n=3$, $x = a$, and replace $b$ with $-b$. We get $a^3 - (-b)^3$ is divisible by  $a - (-b)$.

Comment: To answer the last question on the latest edit, polynomial long division.

Comment: Your idea with the polynomial is fine. You just should write $p(x)\cdot (x-c)=x^3-c^3.$ Then you know that both sides are zero at $x=c.$ You can therefore perform a long division bei $(x^3-c^3):(x-c)=p(x).$ It works like a division of numbers by hand. Here is an example with polynomials: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/constructing-the-splitting-field-for-a-polynomial-over-z-z3.889140/#post-5595083

Comment: Somewhat alternative approach (not worth posting as an answer).  Notice that $$(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3 = (a^3 + b^3) + 3ab(a+b).$$ Therefore, $$~a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)^3 - 3ab(a+b).$$  Therefore, since $~(a+b)~$ is a factor of both of the RHS terms immediately above, it must be a factor of the LHS term.

Comment: A general method that is often useful (it can be modified to work for several variable polynomials) is described in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61058/13130) -- same method several others have described here, but the additional examples in that answer might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are allowed to apply the binomial theorem, we can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
(a + b)^{3} = & {3\choose 0}a^{3}b^{0} + {3\choose 1}a^{2}b^{1} + {3\choose 2}a^{1}b^{2} + {3\choose 3}a^{0}b^{3}\\\\
& = a^{3} + 3a^{2}b + 3ab^{2} + b^{3}\\\\
& = a^{3} + b^{3} + 3ab(a + b)
\end{align*}

Consequently, one arrives at the desired result according to the rearrangement:
\begin{align*}
a^{3} + b^{3} & = (a + b)^{3} - 3ab(a + b)\\\\
& = (a + b)[(a + b)^{2} - 3ab]\\\\
& = (a + b)(a^{2} - ab + b^{2})
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 3):

As other comments and answers have suggested (perhaps indirectly), long division of polynomials—which is an algorithm of repeatedly putting in a term in the quotient that you want then dealing with the consequences—does the trick.

Instead, here's a pretty natural way that you might discover factoring a sum of cubes on your own. (It generalizes to sum of odd powers naturally.)

---

Perhaps you're messing around with Pascal's triangle and binomial powers (as one does), and you write down
$$
(a+b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3. 
$$
Notice the $a^3 + b^3$. Let's isolate it:
$$
a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)^3 - (3a^2b + 3ab^2).
$$
Now, it's pretty clear that $3ab$ is a common factor of the last two terms. Let's pull it out:
$$
a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)^3 - 3ab\, (a + b).
$$
Now, $(a+b)$ is a common factor, which is *fantastic* news. Pull it out and clean up the contents of the quantity on the right:
\begin{align}
a^3 + b^3 
&= (a+b) \, \bigl((a+b)^2 - 3ab \bigr) \\
&= (a+b) \, \bigl(a^2 + 2ab + b^2 - 3ab \bigr) \\
&= (a+b) \,(a^2 - ab + b^2). 
\end{align}
Voilà, sum of cubes!

---

Incidentally, you can produce this identity in one chain of equations, but the *adding and subtracting the same quantity* (in blue) seems to come out of nowhere. It is, of course, motivated by knowing what a binomial cube looks like and the previous *messing around*.

\begin{align}
a^3 + b^3
&= (a^3 \color{blue}{{}+ 3a^2b + 3ab^2} + b^3) \color{blue}{{}- (3a^2b + 3ab^2)} \\
&= (a+b)^3 - 3ab\,(a+b) \\
&= (a+b) \, \bigl((a+b)^2 - 3ab \bigr) \\
&= (a+b) \,(a^2 - ab + b^2) \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Many helpful commenters have suggested polynomial long division to solve the question I posed, and I have carried it out here:

$p(x) \cdot (x+c) = x^3+c^3 \\$

$
p(x) = \frac{x^3+c^3}{x+c}
\\
$

$\begin{array}{r}
x^2-cx+c^2\\
x+c{\overline{\smash{\big)}\,x^3+c^3\phantom{))))))}}}\\
\underline{-(x^3+cx^2)\phantom{))))}}\\
-cx^2+c^3\phantom{))}\\ 
\underline{-(-cx^2-c^2x)}\\ 
c^2x+c^3\phantom{)}\\
\underline{-(c^2x+c^3)}\\ 
0
\end{array}
\\
\\
$

$p(x) = x^2-cx+c^2$

Therefore,

$p(x) \cdot (x+c) = x^3+c^3 \\$

$(x^2-cx+c^2)(x+c) = x^3+c^3$

Answer (score 1):

You can build up $P(x)$ sequentially. To get the term $x^3$ on the right side, first guess $P_1(x) = x^2$. Then $P_1(x) (x + c) = x^3 + x^2 c$. To get rid of this second term on the right side, try $P_2 (x) = P_1(x) - x c$. Then $P_2 (x) (x + c) = x^3 - x c^2$. To get rid of this second term on the right side, take $P_3(x) = P_2(x) + c^2$. We get $P_3(x) (x-c) = x^3 + c^3$ as desired, and we have $P_3(x) = x^2 - xc + c^2$.

Comment: By the way, this is just polynomial long division in disguise!